# Scalar-valued function does not return NULL but a 'NULL' string

Tags: t-sql, user-defined-functions, sql-server-2017

I need to import data from Excel into a ms sql database and I thought using the `OPENROWSET` would be a good idea... well, it is not bad but has some side effects.

The data I'm receiving is not allways 100% correct. By correct I mean cells that should be `NULL` (and in Excel empty) sometimes contain the string `"NULL"` or some other junk like whitespaces. I tried to fix it with this script:

```
GO    
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[NullIfEmpty](@input nvarchar)
RETURNS nvarchar(max)
AS
BEGIN

    if (@input = '' or @input = 'NULL')
    begin
        return NULL
    end

    return @input

END
```

But strange things happen. This gives me a string with the text `"NULL"` instead of a *real* `NULL` so the grid cell after querying the database isn't yellow but contains normal text even though the target column allows `NULL`.

A simple test with:

```
select dbo.nullifempty('NULL')
```

or

```
select dbo.nullifempty(null)
```

also yields a string.

---

Do you know why this is happening and how I can fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get null for empty strings or strings that are the word `NULL`, you could just use `coalesce` and `nullif`:

```
COALESCE(NULLIF(@input, 'NULL'), NULLIF(@Input, ''), @input)
```

Please note that the problem in your original code is because you didn't specify the length of the `@input` parameter - so SQL Server created it as `varchar(1)`.
You should **always** specify length for `char`/`varchar`/`nchar` and `nvarchar`.

From [nchar and nvarchar](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/nchar-and-nvarchar-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) page remarks:

> When n is not specified in a data definition or variable declaration statement, the default length is 1. When n is not specified with the CAST function, the default length is 30.

(`n` referring to the `n` in `nchar(n)` or `nvarchar(n)`)

Comment: that's why there were single `'N'`s in some columns. I didn't know where they came from.

Answer (score 2):

repleace lines with 'ALTER"

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[NullIfEmpty](@input nvarchar(max))
```

and with line with 'if'

```
if (LTRIM(RTRIM(@input)) = '' or @input IS NULL)
```

Comment: This is a nice improvement but still producing a string ;-(

Comment: do you want to return NULL when function called with string 'null' as well ?

Comment: @Vasily and P. ejH - by your powers combined the output is now correct! ;-)

Comment: In the original function, if `@input` is null it should fail the condition and return `@input` - which is `null`...

Answer (score 1):

you should reassign value for declared variable using `set`

```
''''
BEGIN

    if (@input = '' or @input = 'NULL')
    begin
        set @input = NULL
    end

    select @input

END
```

[test](https://rextester.com/STXC17633)

[image]

Comment: ok, now I'm starting to believe my sql server is stupid. Even if I run the example script alone in a new query I still see a string... what happened to my sql server? :-o this can't be :-\